# Meteor Email - Error ECONNRESET while sending email (first time)

Tags: javascript, email, ssl, meteor

I am facing a new issue for me, which I didn’t have on previous application but I am now having on a new one.

I want to have the email verification for Accounts creation but somehow I get an error when the email is supposed to be sent, but only the first email, if I retry to get the email after it works.
I also tried to send a direct Email with `Email.send({})` and same issue : first email has an error and second one is ok.

My MAIL_URL is the classic(I replaced account, domain and PASSWORD with the good data):

> smtps://account@domain.dom:PASSWORD@SSL0.OVH.NET:465

I also tried with smtp and 587 and same issue.

The error is as follow :

```
Exception while invoking method ‘sendEmail’ { Error: read ECONNRESET
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:618:25)
errno: ‘ECONNRESET’,
syscall: ‘read’,
code: ‘ECONNECTION’,
command: ‘CONN’ }
```

The issue is appearing both when I try locally, bringing the Env variable through Meteor.settings or while deployed on Clever Cloud. On both it happens once and then if I retry email gets sent.

Any idea ?

(quick check : One old application that used to work now has the same issue)

Comment: We need a little bit of isolation to debug this problem properly, so how about using this [package](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Mailer) and make sure to set **debug** option to true within `new MailTime(opts)`. Andy to send a mail and see what happens.

Comment: Somehow it seems the problem is coming from OVH. I changed to sendGrid and no more issuers.